# Requests is unable to get page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, user-agent

I am trying to retrieve [this page](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/msft/news-headlines) using Beautiful Soup:

This is the code that I tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/msft/news-headlines")
```

Every time I run my code, it gets stuck and is unable to retrieve the page. However, I received a ReadTimeout exception once (`requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.nasdaq.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=None)`).

Any help or fix for this problem will be truly appreciated.

Comment: This code is attempting to read a URL using `requests`, not BeautifulSoup. It seems that the website you are making the request to sends a lot of data or never really closes the connection, causing either the `ReadTimeout` you mentioned, or it just hangs. I am not sure of a solution, but I'm sure looking into something like "Why requests.get hangs" will result in something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included headers in my request and it seemed to work. I used the same headers that my browser sends, which you can find using the developer tools (as [indicated here](https://mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/)).

```
import requests

headers = {
    "authority": "www.nasdaq.com",
    "method": "GET",
    "path": "/market-activity/stocks/msft/news-headlines",
    "scheme": "https",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-CA,en;q=0.9,ro-RO;q=0.8,ro;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "dnt": "1",
    "if-modified-since": "Tue, 30 Jun 2020 19:43:05 GMT",
    "if-none-match": "1593546185",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "none",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"
}

page = requests.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/msft/news-headlines", headers=headers)
```

Comment: I suspect that only the user-agent portion is needed in the headers e.g. `"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36"`. You could try just including just the `user-agent` field in the headers.

Comment: I second @zmike's comment. It is very common IME for sites to require a "legitimate" user-agent header. I say legitimate because some will reject a request for not having a particularly "normal" user-agent header, which could of course be perfectly legitimate, though strange.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/msft/news-headlines")
```

Try retreiving the webpage this way:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

page = Request("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/msft/news-headlines")
```